# 2006 katana 750 help

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, suzuki, katana

Haven't been able to ride because of injury for months. Tried to start bike of course battery dead. Charge for day turns a couple times then battery to weak to turn anymore. So jump from car. Get it started runs for a min  then bike completely dies. No power to anything not even the clock. Check battery it was bad anyways so replaced still nothing. Fuse is next stop. Could I have broke something when jumping.

Comment: Check the spark plug, fuel lines, pump and injectors.

Comment: It's a power issue not a fuel issue. Plug is good.

Comment: Can you share the picture of the plug? Most times a bad starter motor or a distributor can cause this. But before we play the guessing game it's best to run tests on all possibilities. I suggest you start with the fuel pump and go until the injector. You have not used your suzuki for a while. Again if you think its electrical, even a fuel pump is electrically operated just the same an injector would be.

Comment: @Solar Mike can you help?